# c# error to cast object of type with sql query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

When I try out this query

```
select Category,ItemName,ItemBrand,ItemLocation,Qty,Date ,+'0000'+convert (varchar, ItemId)
```

as testing from  Inventory in my SSMS . It works fine.

When I use the query in  c# window form it will show error

> Error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System. String'

```
      private void databaseLoading()
    {
        query = "select Category,ItemName,ItemBrand,ItemLocation,Qty,Date ,+'0000'+convert (varchar, ItemId) as testing from  Inventory";
        //query = "select * from Inventory";
        exeQuery = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
        try
        {
            sqlconn.Open();
            // must close after use and less memory use
            sqlReader = exeQuery.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                string Catg = sqlReader.GetString(1).ToString();
                string Name = sqlReader.GetString(2).ToString();
                string Brand = sqlReader.GetString(3).ToString();
                string location = sqlReader.GetString(4).ToString();
                cbxCatg.Items.Add(Catg);
                cbxItemName.Items.Add(Name);
                cbxBrand.Items.Add(Brand);
                cbxLocation.Items.Add(location);
            }
            sqlconn.Close();
            sqlconn.Open();
            // dataadapter it may auto close connection but it need more memory cause it will load all information to the table
            sqlAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(exeQuery);

            sqlAdp.Fill(dt);
            dgvInventory.DataSource = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: you should give us more details. Where the exception was thrown?

Comment: And in particular, which line is throwing the exception? My guess is that `Category` is an integer field rather than a text-based field.

Comment: SSMS is a tool for SQL Server. `SqlCommand` can only work with SQL Server. Based on that I've removed the MySql tag and added an SQL Server tag instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet no, all is varchar except Qty.

Comment: This is where it's useful to know the schema to start with, along with exactly which line is throwing the exception. This specific question is answered now, but it would be good to bear this in mind for future questions. (I'd missed the off-by-one error before.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a type of a column in sql server is int, then you should use `GetInt32()` in the reader, not `GetString()`.
In addition, your first select item is a category `query = "select Category`, so in the reader the string `Catg` must have index 0 `GetString(0)`

Answer (score 0):

One of your database column might be `int`.
Use:

```
sqlReader.GetInt32(1).ToString()
```

instead